# Adding Apache Shiro parameters into web.xml unables correct app deployment

Tags: maven, netbeans, web.xml, shiro

I have been trying to use Apache Shiro in my java web project but I have read all the tutorials and examples to no avail. My app was running okay until I created the web.xml file and included the following lines:

```
<listener>
 <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
 <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
 <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
 <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
 <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Also, I am using Netbeans as IDE and not using Maven because I don't know how to use it, I did try to follow the tutorials with a simple Maven proyect, though. I would like to hear a solution with no Maven in it please.

For more information about my proyect structure, here it is.

NetBeans 8.0
Java Web Application

Libraries under WEB-INF/lib/
shiro-core-1.2.3.jar
shiro-web-1.2.3.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.2.jar

Those are included using the Netbeans include libraries.

I would like some guidance over this because I have not found pretty much information on using Shiro without Maven. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there any exception or error you are getting ?

Comment: The only thing is that Proyect could not be deployed and in Apache Log it says that it couldn't run because of previous errors. It says something about Filter Start but I don't get what it is. If I delete the above code section, everything runs fine.

Comment: where you have put shiro.ini file ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no information about a xml file for shiro. The only new files I created as mentioned in every tutorial are shiro.ini and  web.xml so no idea about shiro.xml file. Am I missing something more?

Comment: sorry I was asking about shiro.ini file.

Comment: No problem. The shiro.ini is located under WEB-INF directory and has the minimun code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75081/discussion-between-sachin-gupta-and-ditmark12).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sachin Gupta for the support. It was some missing libraries that prevented my project to run correctly since Maven already sets up the required ones according to Sachin so I must have included them but couldn't find the error precisely.

These are the following:

commons-beanutils-1.9.2
commons-logging-1.2
slf4j-api-1.7.2

I appreciate the help provided by Sachin over this issue.